# How to return multiple max values when there are duplicates in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates, max, google-sheets-formula

Relatively simple question, but can't seem to figure it out. I'm using a formula `(INDEX('Key1'!$A$2:$D$68, MATCH(MAX('Key1'!$D$2:$D$68), 'Key1'!$D$2:$D$68, 0), 1), "")` that returns the categorical variable with the highest score. The formula works, but it there are multiple categorical variables that scored 100%, hence, multiple matches. That being said, Sheets just returns that first categorical variable it finds that scored 100% and then stops. How can I return all the categorical variables that achieved the max score, since there are multiple?

Comment: use query instead of single match

Comment: Post some sample data and desired output.

Comment: Give a try on `=FILTER('Key1'!$A$2:$D$68,'Key1'!$D$2:$D$68=MAX('Key1'!$D$2:$D$68))`.

Comment: Or using Query `=QUERY('Key1'!$A$2:$D$68, "select * where D=" & MAX('Key1'!$D$2:$D$68))`.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output